# What is the minimum requirement to extend Schengen visa without any official reservations?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, indian-citizens, international-travel

I secured a French Schengen visa from February to May.
I wanted to do a solo trip, but after looking at the prices of travel and living, I decided going with someone else was the best course of action.

My friend wants to go next January though. This means I might have to extend my visa.

If I don't travel at all during the approved period, could that affect my chances of approval later?

If yes, would it help if I just traveled to Athens for a few days? I have a layover in Istanbul.

Indian citizen/ Canadian PR.

Comment: Why would they extend a visa when you haven't entered the country, or only for a few days? The visa dates can't be changed, but you could reapply: it's 7 months later. An unused visa doesn't penalise another application. There are many reasons why someone might not travel when they intend to, but have to defer it.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a mechanism for extending a C visa other than in force majeure circumstances, so your chances of ‘approval later’ are zero, unless you mean approval of another visa.

Answer (score 9):

> If I don't travel at all during my approved duration, could that affect my chances of approval later?

You do not need to justify why you did not use a visa.

> I secured a French Schengen Visa ... would it help if I just travel to Athens for a few days?

Not only would it **not** help, but it could affect future applications since your given **main destination** was France and you only went to Greece.

> What is the minimum requirement to extend Schengen visa without any official reservations?

You cannot extend a Schengen visa. A new application is required for the new time period.

Answer (score -2):

While the Schengen visa code technically allows you to enter any country within the Schengen area and stay for the duration of your visa, it is advisable to adhere to the main destination you specified. In practical terms, if you designated France as your primary destination, it is best to travel there. Deviating from this plan could raise suspicions during future visa applications, potentially leading to consequences such as being accused of visa shopping. It's important to proceed with caution in such situations.

In short you must apply for a new visa if there is any change in your plans.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about changing the length of the visa as well as the destination.

Comment: Do you think @Willeke embassies would change the length of the visa as well as the destination

Comment: No, I think they do not, but that is what OP asks about and you ignored that in the answer.

Comment: The visa code does not forsee such changes. A visa can be **revoked** at the request of the visa holder based on Article 34 (3), afterwhich a new visa can be applied for.

Comment: Visa code allows entry to any Schengen zone. It does but in special circumstances perhaps read the code with full detail. Check article 33 of the community code

Comment: @Willeke think my question targets that

Comment: Article 33 (Extension) of the visa code has **absolutely** nothing to do with a visa that has not been used. It is only about an extension due to ***force majeure** or humanitarian reasons **preventing him from leaving** the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the period of validity of or the duration of stay authorised by the visa*.

Comment: @SaranshSharma, visa questions require special knowledge as a wrong advice can cost people a lot of money and can lead to bans which affect their future travel often for many years. Do not post answers if you are not really sure, giving people advice to double check or to proceed with caution should be extra, on top of a first class answer. Your answers do not have the required quality in my opinion. (Nor would mine have which is why I rarely post that kind of answers.)

Comment: Your answers and comment in the good void space since user is essentially trying to enter before the period date it is self explanatory that he wants to enter before the period set date. Which is not possible. Correct the unused visa cannot be extended but you have assumed that I was advising for so

Comment: Where do one get this special knowledge? By experiences or by working at a visa office is so then none of the answers should be taken as advice